# Is there a library which supports bluetooth 2.0 for xamarin?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I'm trying to make a bluetooth communication on xamarin for ios. I already tried core bluetooth and monkey robotics bluetooth but neither of them worked. I looked somethings up on google and found out that it's not possible to communicate with a BLE 2.0. Even the ipad I'm testing doesn't recognise the device I'm trying to connect.

Thank you

Comment: Bluetooth Low-Energy 2.0 ? What's that? I couldn't find any information about it. Are you sure it's not Bluetooth 2.0? Which in that case has to be MFi and you should use `ExternalAccessory.framework` ?

Comment: Yes, it's a Bluetooth 2.0, my bad. I will take a look at that, thank you Larme